# Verifying domain owner

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, controller, net-http

I'm trying to verify whether a user has control of a domain as part of my rails 3 app by uploading a randomly generated file to the root of their domain (the same way google does it for google apps). Currently I'm using Net::HTTP and it seems to work if the address is valid but if the address is not valid I get this error.

```
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Is there a way to somehow ignore this error or a better/ different way to wrtite the code for the controller?

```
def check
  require 'net/http'
  require 'uri'
  result = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('http://www.example.com/21312324213123.html'))
  if Net::HTTPSuccess
      @test = "true"
  else
      @test = "false"
  end
end
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is rescue from that exception and return that as a separate case.

```
def check
  # ...
rescue => e
  # Uh oh, got an exception
  @error = e.to_s
  @test = "false"
end
```

Comment: Thanks tadman that works. Still very new to ruby so I didn't even know rescue was an option.

Comment: The best practice is to `rescue` from the specific exception you received to avoid hiding more severe errors. In this case you might get a variety of them, though, so it's probably safer to capture and report on them. A Timeout error will also occur if the page couldn't be downloaded quickly enough, or the server was not responding.